# Ng-select style issue

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

[image]After install ng-select with :

```
npm install --save @ng-select/ng-select
```

I'm importing the material style to styles.scss with :

```
@import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/material.theme.css";
```

body {

But after all, the component is being presented with a very strange appearance.

Lookin at node_modules folder I can't see the ng-select folder to look at it's themes folder.

Any ideas please ?

Comment: remove node modules and reinstall everything

Comment: Did it but with no results. The font is something like courier and the component caption is too small.

Comment: @GCoe Can you show your view code? That looks like a multi-select box.

Comment: Shure @AvinKavish : 

<ng-select [(ngModel)]="talhoesSelecionados" 
(change)="resetarRegistrosDeProducaoSelecionados()"
[items]="talhoes"
[multiple]="true"
[closeOnSelect]="false"
bindLabel="DescricaoDoTalhao"
bindValue="CodigoDoTalhao"
placeholder="Selecione o talhão"
[(ngModel)]="talhoesSelecionados">
</ng-select>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved with :

```
@import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/material.theme.css"; at styles.css
```

and

```
style="font-family: roboto" at the ng-select tag
```

Comment: Is it like this: ng-select {style = "font-family: roboto"}

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 13
Add this code in your angular.json styles block :

```
       "styles": [
         ....
         ....
          "node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css",
        ],
```